# How to constraint a fragment to a appbar in coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

I need to connect a fragment inside of an activity(that is written in constraint layout) to an AppBar (written in coordinator layout, outside of the constraint layout). The problem is that the fragment starts from the parent and not below the AppBar. My best idea was to put a guideline inside of the activity so I could constraint the fragment to the guideline instead of the AppBar. The problem is that I would have to put the same guideline to every activity I implement that fragment to, and i want to avoid that. Its all basically just so I could reuse the fragment just as it is at the moment, not needing to change its dimensions so it could fit in the part of the activity. Here is a part of the XML code. I'm just looking for better solutions in which the fragment would be truly reusable.

```
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <include layout="@layout/item_view_toolbar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
   <fragment
            android:id="@+id/profile_fragment"
            android:name="xxx.contractor.ui.fragment.ProfileFragment_"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Could you post the full code of the layout ?

Comment: Why do you need to connect it ?